# Validating string using RegEx

Tags: regex

I need a Regular expression to validate string for below rules.

1. String should not contain any repeated characters more than 2 times.
2. String should not allow special characters like &, <, %

So far I managed to create regular expression

```
/(?!(.)\1{2,})^([a-zA-Z0-9''\.\-\,]+\s?)*$/i
```

which validates rules 1 & 2. But only problem what I have is it only validates rule at the start of string.

Comment: Any feedback on the two answers you received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regex to

```
/(?!.*(.)\1{2,})^([a-zA-Z0-9'".,-]+\s?)*$/i
    ^^
```

It will allow the negative lookahead to work on the whole regex instead of the beginning.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gU0dM0/1)

Comment: Why isn't `[a-zA-Z0-9]` `[\w]`?

Comment: @HappyCoding because `\w` also include the `_`

Answer (score 2):

For your negative lookahead to work, you have to make it so it could match a 3-in-a-row at any place in the validated string ; just add a `.*` at its start :

```
/(?!.*(.)\1{2,})^([a-zA-Z0-9'".\-,]+\s?)*$/i
```

I also changed your two consecutive single-quotes in your character class to the single-quote and double quote I assume you want to allow and removed   unnecessary backslashes escapes.